# DeleteCases using two lists but with partial match?

Tags: pattern-matching, filtering

I searched and tried different solutions on SE but nothing worked.

I have two lists and would like to remove items from `list1` that have a PARTIAL match with items in `list2`. I'm new to this.

I tried this but it didn't filter anything out

```
Select[list1, ! MemberQ[list2, #] &]
```

I also tried with `DeleteCases` and `StringMatchQ` but only got various errors. I tried a few solutions from SE but none worked for my specific case.

```
list1 = {"http://www.domain.com/research", "http://www.domain.com/signup", "tel:5559986644", "mailto:info@domain.com"}

list2 = {"tel:", "mailto:"}

results = {"http://www.domain.com/research", "http://www.domain.com/signup"}
```

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
Cases[_?(Not@*StringContainsQ[Alternatives @@ list2])]@list1
Cases[Except[_?(StringContainsQ[Alternatives@@list2])]]@list1
DeleteCases[_?(StringContainsQ[Alternatives @@ list2])]@list1
Select[list1, Not @* StringContainsQ[Alternatives @@ list2]]
```

all give

> {"http://www.domain.com/research", "http://www.domain.com/signup"}

You can also use the pattern `_?(StringMatchQ[#, "*" ~~ Alternatives @@ list2 ~~ "*"]&)`, or `_?(StringMatchQ["*" ~~ Alternatives @@ list2 ~~ "*"])`, e.g.,

```
DeleteCases[list1, _?(StringMatchQ[#,"*" ~~ Alternatives @@ list2 ~~"*"]&)]
DeleteCases[list1, _?(StringMatchQ["*" ~~ Alternatives @@ list2 ~~"*"])]
```

> same result

Comment: This is great, but I could have explained that keywords are not necessarily at the start of the string. They should match anywhere in the string. Some URL values may be http://www.domain.com/signup/ and the keyword would be "signup" to filter those out.  Right now using DeleteCases[list1, _?(StringMatchQ[#,Alternatives @@ list2~~"*"]&)] deletes everything.

Comment: @SamB, change `StringStartsQ` to `StringContainsQ` and `StringMatchQ[#,Alternatives @@ list2~~"*"]&` to `StringMatchQ[#,"*"~~Alternatives @@ list2~~"*"]&`

Comment: `list1 = {"http://www.domain.com/research", 
   "http://www.domain.com/signup", "tel:5559986644", 
   "mailto:info@domain.com", "http://www.domain.com/departments"};`  
  
`list2 = {"tel:", "mailto:", "signup"};`  
  
`Select[list1, _?(StringContainsQ[#, 
     "*" ~~ Alternatives @@ list2 ~~ "*"] &)]`  
  
Out = { }

Comment: @SamB, you need to use `Select[list1, StringContainsQ[Alternatives @@ list2] ]` or 
  `Select[list1, StringMatchQ[#,"*"~~Alternatives @@ list2~~"*"]& ]` (or `Select[list1, StringMatchQ["*"~~Alternatives @@ list2~~"*"] ]`).

Comment: Thank you @kglr!  The final thing I did to get what I wanted was this:

`DeleteCases[list1,_?( StringContainsQ[Alternatives @@ list2])]`